# Как удалить сообщения в чате тг, если в сообщении есть ключевое слово

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Пытаюсь сделать чат-бот модератор, который будет удалять сообщения, если в них будут определенные слова. Пока только сделал удаление системных сообщений о добавлении и выходе из чата.

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("")
GROUP_ID = -123456

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members', 'left_chat_member'])
def delete(message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
bot.polling()
```

подскажите как реализовать идею.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Обработчик сообщений, подходящих под указанное регулярное выражение
@bot.message_handler(regexp="SOME_REGEXP")
def handle_message(message):
    pass
```

Используй регулярные выражения
Если что вот хорошая статья про [регулярки](https://habr.com/ru/post/349860/)